# Can NW.JS write web form data to a local text file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

I am new to NW.JS and was wondering if it is possible to to save form data from a html form in the app to a text file locally. I am new to javascript coming from python and I get the whole same origin policy thing with NW.JS and how it can be overridden, I just can’t figure out how to do this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what system are you working on? it is possible you just have to tell nwjs where to save it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using any write module. However you have to tell him the path where you want to write it.

```
let home = process.env.HOME
```

this gives you your home directory

```
var writeFile = require('write');
writeFile(home + '/foo.txt', 'This is content...', function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```